# When start Azure cosmos db emulator It is show Unable to add firewall rule settings. Please restart the Azure Cosmos Emulator with/NoFirewall Option

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I installed Azure cosmos db Emulator in my office laptop. First it is shows 8081 already running. I changed the port issue resolved.

But it showing **Unable to add firewall rule settings. Please restart the Azure Cosmos Emulator with/NOFirewall Option**.

I try with below 2 commands in CMD

`Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /NoFirewall   Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /port=1729/NOFirewall Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe [/NOFirewall] [/port=1729]`

But I the issue not resolved. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgw2G.png
```

Comment: can you try the comment https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/470 by ToddTaylor

Comment: @Sajeetharan Hi, I tried. Issue not resolved

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate a new authorization key and save to the specified file. The generated key can be used with the /Key or /KeyFile options.

   Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /GenKeyFile=<path to key file
2. If the emulator is already running, shut it off.
3. Next, remove the emulator's data directory from the following path:
   (C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\CosmosDBEmulator)
4. Run the following command to restart the emulator:

   /AllowNetworkAccess /KeyFile=generatedKey /NoFirewall /Port=#####

Please  refer for the [command-line parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator-command-line-parameters) or to [Troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-local-emulator) issues when using the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator

**Note:** You can use any port you like, but make sure it isn't currently in use. For the data explorer to continue operating, you must replace your created key with the default key.

Comment: Hi , Thank you very much. I tried above steps. when I execute Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /GenKeyFile=<C:\Users\myusernmae\azureFile. It gives Access denied. I don't have admin rights the for system. system admin download the Azure cosmos db emulator. I am trying to use it.  is there any solution to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Kindly check if your system has admin rights. If not you will be needing to get it by adding your id local admin list.

1. Open CMD
2. Type lusrmgr. It will redirect you to Local Users and Groups.
3. Enter Groups.
4. Open Administrator.
5. Select Add.
6. Under Enter the object names to select provide your primary email Id.
   Restart.

And voila you are now the admin of your system.